# How to get last node in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a chat app where user can see last message of conversation. But I am stuck with this situation where i am unable to get last message.

I have tried this query like

```
DatabaseReference getLastMessageRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FriendsMessages");
Query query1 = getLastMessageRef.child(common.currentUser.getPhone()).child(id).orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
```

Where `common.currentUser.getPhone` is number/id of current user and id is id of other person.

And database structure is like [DATABASE STRUCTURE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCrNN.jpg)

```
private void getAllMessages() {

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FriendsMessages").child(common.currentUser.getPhone());
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MessageModel> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MessageModel>()
            .setQuery(query,MessageModel.class)
            .build();


    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MessageModel, ShowAllMessageViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ShowAllMessageViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final MessageModel model) {


            String id = adapter.getRef(position).getKey();

            DatabaseReference getFriendDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
            DatabaseReference getLastMessageRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FriendsMessages");


            getFriendDataRef.child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                        String dp = dataSnapshot.child("img").getValue().toString();
                        String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();

                        holder.MessageName.setText(name);
                        Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(dp).into(holder.messageDp);

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


            Query query1 = getLastMessageRef.child(common.currentUser.getPhone()).child(id).orderByKey().limitToLast(1);

            query1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String mesaage = (String) dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue();

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+mesaage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ShowAllMessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_message_view,parent,false);

            return new ShowAllMessageViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    showAllMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I am getting null string.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to remember is that Firebase keys are always Strings. And when strings are ordered, are [ordered lexicographically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647150/how-to-order-the-nodes-in-firebase-console-based-on-key).

If you want to get the last element, add to each message object a new property that can hold a `timestamp`. **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)** is how you can add it to the database and get it back. In the end, simply create a query and order the elements according to this new timestamp property and call `limitToLast(1)`. That's it!

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for answering but i just wanted ask like my query was right no?

Comment: No, it's not. It will never return the last item according to a time component. It will retrun a last element. You cannot order according those strings and expect to behave as it were timestamps.

Comment: i want last element only but it's retrieving it. Giving me null error

Comment: Have you tried to hardcode the values of `common.currentUser.getPhone()` and `id` in your query `Query query1 = getLastMessageRef.child(common.currentUser.getPhone()).child(id).orderByKey().limitToLast(1);`? Does it work that way?

Comment: yes i have passed value like Query query1 = getLastMessageRef.child(common.currentUser.getPhone()).child(id).child("Name of node"); and was working

Comment: It means that your values are wrong. Be sure to have the correct values and it will work.

Comment: both of them having a stored corrected values. I dont know why its not working with OrderByKey.LimitToLast

Comment: Check the value that you are getting in field "id", if you are getting null then the id value might be incorrect.