# Save date in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Now my working code is where I save the date as String is [here](https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/5940e50147060dd7976451cab6165690)

Now i want save date as a `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43584581/6387618)

So first i tried to modified my model:

```
data class Target(
    val guid: String = "",
    val name: String = "",
    val description: String = "",
    val timestamp: MutableMap<String, Any>? = mutableMapOf()
)
```

after in presenter write smth like this:

```
fun addTarget(name: String, description: String, timestamp: ServerValue) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            val id: String = databaseReference?.push()?.key.toString()
            val map = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
            map.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
            val target = Target(guid = id, name = name, description = description, timestamp = map)
            targetsRef?.push()?.setValue(target)
        } else Log.d("some", "Enter a name")
    }
```

But parameter `timestamp` is never used.

Also in fragment i need Map, but get String, because i take it from dateView text

```
val date = dateView?.text.toString().trim()
```

in method:

```
override fun editTarget(targetGuid: String) {
        val name = nameEditText?.text.toString().trim()
        val description = descriptionEditText?.text.toString().trim()
        val date = dateView?.text.toString().trim()
        presenter.addTarget(name, description, date)
    }
```

**UPD:**
This is how i take date from my DatePickerDialog:

```
private fun showDatePickerDialog() {
        val date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        val currentYear = date.year
        val currentMonth = date.monthValue
        val currentDay = date.dayOfMonth

        val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)

        pickDate.setOnClickListener {
            val datePickDialog = DatePickerDialog(
                activity,
                R.style.DatePickerDialogTheme,
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                    val selectedDate = LocalDate.of(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth)
                    val dateString = selectedDate.format(dateFormatter)
                    dateView.text = dateString
                },
                currentYear,
                currentMonth - 1,
                currentDay
            )
            datePickDialog.show()

            datePickDialog.setOnCancelListener { dialog -> dialog.dismiss() }
        }
    }
```

And after this i take smth like this

```
val date = dateView?.text.toString().trim()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the selected date like this and get the epoch milliseconds

```
val parsedDate = LocalDate.parse("your-date-here", dateFormatter)
val milliseconds = parseDate.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()
```

you can then save the milliseconds to database. `atStartOfDay()` will set the time to midnight.

Comment: in presenter i haven't a problem, i have in fragment, when i need take text from dateView. I added more information about problem check please method editTarget. I need a date which i should to push in firebase

Comment: So you want to save a date and timestamp separately into firebase database?

Comment: No
I want to create a date for my target.
Follow this advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58012986/6387618

Comment: I need "consider storing the date as a ServerValue.TIMESTAMP"

Comment: I cannot understand why you need ServerValue.TIMESTAMP. Because if you want to save the selected date as a epoch timestamp you can parse the selected date and convert it to milliseconds. ServerValue.TIMESTAMP will save the server timestamp to database.

Comment: Maybe I didn't quite understand how to do it. Let us on order. I have a DatePickerDialog from where I take the date as a string. How can I further convert this String to a Date?

Comment: You can use SimpleDateFormatter to parse the string into date. What is the selected date string format? I will update the code occordingly

Comment: You can use this to parse date. It 

```
val parsedDate = LocalDate.parse("your-date-here", dateFormatter)
```

Comment: Ok, i get it  parsedDate: `2019-09-21`. what are my next steps?

Comment: Since you only need the date and not time, you can do something like this
`val parsedDate = LocalDate.parse("your-date-here", dateFormatter) `
`parsedDate.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()`

That would give you the milliseconds for the selected date, which can be saved to firebase database

Comment: @SasiKanth Nice solution Sasi. Using that will help Morozon query the database using that long value in `whereEqual(parsedDate)`.