# How to get retrieve items from the following realtime database structure?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg0TS.png)

I'm completely new to realtime database and nosql and want some help.
How do I fetch all the data. from only the keys starting with 2020, from the following database structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I fetch all the data. from only the keys starting with 2020, from the following database structure?

Firebase doesn't provide a way to filter the records by keys that start with a particular String. The most simple solution I can think of is to change the "year" property in your database to be of type number and **not** String, otherwise, you'll have a [lexicographical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647150/how-to-order-the-nodes-in-firebase-console-based-on-key). To solve this, you need to use a query that looks like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference calendarRef = rootRef.child("calendar");
Query yearQuery = calendarRef.orderByChild("year").startAt(2000).endAt(2001);
yearQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

This will return all records where the "year" property holds the value of **2000**.

Comment: Good to hear that. You're very welcome, cheers!