# How to save large arrayList in the same order as it is to firebase database in kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

I am trying to save a list of data to the Firebase Realtime Database in Kotlin. But when I try to save the order gets shuffled as below.

[image]

This is my code. Here the `locationlist` is the array that contains the list of locations that I want to save in the same order as it is. But when I try to save the after the first element, 10th element is showed. And the pattern continues like that.

```
 ref.child(pk).child("location${count+1}").setValue(locationList).addOnCompleteListener {

                Toast.makeText(requireContext() ,"success$pk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


            }
```

Comment: What is the exact order that you are looking for?

Comment: like 0,1,2,3...etc in ascending order to the end which is the actual arraylist order.

Comment: And you want this order in console or in the code?

Comment: In the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an ascending order in code, the following lines will keep the order that exist in the array. Assuming you have a property "name" within each object, please try the following code:

```
    val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    val locationRef = rootRef.child("location2")
    locationRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            for (ds in task.result.children) {
                val name = ds.child("name").getValue(String::class.java)
                Log.d(TAG, name!!)
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.exception!!.message!!) //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to change the order in the Firebase Console, please note that this is not possible. Check for a workaround in my answer from the following post:

- [How to order the nodes in firebase console based on key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647150/how-to-order-the-nodes-in-firebase-console-based-on-key)

Comment: I am getting error when typing `locationRef.get()`.

Comment: What error? Show me the code or screenshot.

Comment: I had to add a gradle build dependency. Now everything is working fine