# How to write a query to sort the Orders according to "Time"?

Tags: java, android, firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

My database **(Firebase Realtime Database)** looks like this:

[image: here is the image]

The code I wrote for sorting the orders acc. to Time:

```
val myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders");
myRef.orderByChild("Time").addValueEventListener(orderListener)
```

But this won't work?
I think my argument to orderByChild method is wrong. How to fix this?

Comment: "But this won't work? I" Why not? It easiest to help if you show the code that reproduces your actual problem. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code looks fine. Can you also show us how you use it further and also what do you mean with "won't work". Do you get any data? Is it not sorted as expected? Consider also that you store the data as `String` and it will be sorted as a `String` data type and not as time or number.

Comment: Hadn't indexed the firebase database rules. Using .IndexOn made it work!
Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to get the data, you have to attach a listener on the Query object and iterate through the results as you can see in the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val ordersRef = rootRef.child("Orders")
val queryByTime = ordersRef.orderByChild("Time")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val phone = ds.child("Phone").getValue(String::class.java)
            Log.d("TAG", phone)
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
queryByTime.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

Since your "Time" property is of type String, you may not get the best results, since the ordering is done lexicographically:

- [How to order the nodes in firebase console based on key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647150/how-to-order-the-nodes-in-firebase-console-based-on-key)

So the best option the you have is to change the type of the field from String to a number.