# Data not showing after getting refrence from the root node firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

After removing the parent node and getting all the child nodes from root node directly

I'm not getting any data

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        model = new Model();
        quotes_list = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    model = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model.class);
                    if (model != null) {
                        quotes_list.add(model.getTitle());
                        position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());

                    }
                }
                quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
                countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());

            }
```

[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c7T7TwfvcBhl8eg8FoBFoZU984xi-MPH/view?usp=sharing) is the json of firebase

Comment: Is your onDataChange even triggered?

Comment: before removing the parent node it was working all good

Comment: Do you have the exact same structure now?

Comment: no actually when i import the json in firebase , it changed

Comment: changed becuse of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647150/how-to-order-the-nodes-in-firebase-console-based-on-key

Comment: I answered that question, as well as [yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72571086/5246885). Did that answer help?